# Calculating number of months between 2 dates from SAS INTCK to Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sas

I have the following SAS date logic to extract 'number of months' between 2 dates and appreciate if anyone can help me as how do I get this done in Python/Pandas dataframe

```
%let orig_val=10;
%let mydate1="17JUL2019:00:00:00";
%let mydate2="31DEC2019"d;
%let curmth=0;

if &orig_val in (4,10,12) then 
  num_mths =intck('month',datepart(&mydate1), intnx('month', input(symget('&mydate2'), date9.), -(&curmth+1), "end"));
```

in my actual code, &curmth value comes from a macro variable and it can be any number from 0 to 20 or more but &mydate2 is always same 31Dec2019 date.

Explanation of how the above above line of code will resolve for different 'curmth' and 'mydate1' values:

*When &curmth=0 and &mydate1=17JUL2019, for the 2nd date calculation, it subtracts &mydate2-(&curmth+1) =31Dec2019-(0+1)= 30Nov2019
(note: 2nd date always resolves to the last day of that month as we are using 'end' parameter to do so) and resolves as below*

```
** num_mths=intck('month','17JUL2019','30NOV2019') ***
```

and calculates number of months difference between 17jul2019 and 30Nov2019 as num_mnths which is 4:

Similarly for other dates examples:

when curmth=2 and mydate1=25MAR2019, it resolves as below and calculates the output num_mnths as 6:

```
** num_mths=intck('month','25MAR2019','30SEP2019') ***;
```

when curmth=5 and mydate1=14OCT2018,it resolves as below and calculates the output num_mnths as 8:

```
** num_mths=intck('month','14OCT2018','30JUN2019') ***;
```

when curmth=11 and mydate1=07NOV2017, it resolves as below and calculates the output num_mnths as 13:

```
** num_mths=intck('month','07NOV2017','31DEC2018') ***;
```

when curmth=12 and mydate1=16AUG2018, it resolves as below and calculates the output num_mnths as 3:

```
** num_mths=intck('month','16AUG2018','30NOV2018') ***;

expected output examples
 1) when &mydate1='18MAR2019:00:00:00' and &curmth=0, then num_mths=8 
 2) when &mydate1='15JUL2019:00:00:00' and &curmth=1, then num_mths=3
 3) when &mydate1='19FEB2019:00:00:00' and &curmth=2, then num_mths=7
 4) when &mydate1='11MAR2019:00:00:00' and &curmth=3, then num_mths=5
 5) when &mydate1='04SEP2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=4, then num_mths=10
 6) when &mydate1='14OCT2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=5, then num_mths=8
 7) when &mydate1='17MAY2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=6, then num_mths=12
 8) when &mydate1='18JUL2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=6, then num_mths=9
.....
.....
9) when &mydate1='07NOV2017:00:00:00' and &curmth=11, then num_mths=13
10)when &mydate1='16AUG2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=12, then num_mths=3
11)when &mydate1='14JUN2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=13, then num_mths=4
12)when &mydate1='23FEB2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=14, then num_mths=7
13)when &mydate1='17APR2018:00:00:00' and &curmth=15, then num_mths=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate months in SAS, INTCK and INTNX are used, there is no exactly the same function in Python, but it is calculated by only Pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

mydate1=pd.Timestamp('2019-07-15')
mydate2=pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31')
curmth=1

print(mydate1,mydate2,cumth)

2019-07-15 00:00:00 2019-12-31 00:00:00 1

# INTNX function; pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) convert date to end date of the month;  
newdate=mydate2-pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=curmth+1)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)

# INTCK function
print(newdate.year-mydate1.year)*12+(newdate.month-mydate1.month))
3
```

**Set Python function like SAS macro program**

```
def month(mydate1,curmth):
    newdate=mydate2-pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=curmth+1)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
    months=(newdate.year-mydate1.year)*12+(newdate.month-mydate1.month)
    return months
mydate1=pd.Timestamp('2018-07-18')
curmth=6

month(mydate1,curmth)
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, as per my SAS code,  when mydate1=2018-07-18 and curmth=6, num_mths should be 9 and not 10.

Comment: Is it intnx('month', &mydate2, -(&curmth+1), "end")? so it is -7, not -6, the final month is also 10 by SAS.

Comment: Yes, it's &curnth+1 and your answer above is correct. I was checking for bunch of dates and I think I got mixed up. My bad..

Comment: Can you pls help me with the equivalent python code for the below sas code? I tried using your logic, but unable to get the reqd o/p. Thanks! :%let max_num_mths=12;
%let mydate1='01jun2010'd;
%let mydate2='31DEC2019'd;

call symput ('months_Back', min (symget('max_num_mths'),(intck('month', input(symget('mydate1'), date9.),intnx('month', input(symget('mydate2'), date9.), 0, "end")) + 1)));

Answer (score 1):

**Dataframe creation**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'mydate1':['17JUL2019:00:00:00','18MAR2019:00:00:00',
               '27MAR2019:00:00:00','04SEP2018:00:00:00',
              '07NOV2017:00:00:00','23FEB2018:00:00:00'],
    'mydate2':'31Dec2019',
    'curmth':[0,0,1,4,11,14]
})
df.mydate1 = pd.to_datetime(df.mydate1, format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
df.mydate2 = pd.to_datetime(df.mydate2, format='%d%b%Y', )
df
```

**Input Sample**

```
    mydate1 mydate2       curmth
0   2019-07-17  2019-12-31  0
1   2019-03-18  2019-12-31  0
2   2019-03-27  2019-12-31  1
3   2018-09-04  2019-12-31  4
4   2017-11-07  2019-12-31  11
5   2018-02-23  2019-12-31  14
```

**Code for diff in months**

```
mnth_diff = (df.mydate2 - df.mydate1)//np.timedelta64(1,'M')
df['num_mths']=mnth_diff-df.curmth-1
df
```

**Output**

```
    mydate1 mydate2 curmth  num_mths
0   2019-07-17  2019-12-31  0   4
1   2019-03-18  2019-12-31  0   8
2   2019-03-27  2019-12-31  1   7
3   2018-09-04  2019-12-31  4   10
4   2017-11-07  2019-12-31  11  13
5   2018-02-23  2019-12-31  14  7
```

**Explanation**

We are finding the diff between two months using `np.timedelta`.

Comment: Thanks @Uts for your solution and it looks good. But, will this work when 'curmth' value is any number? Because, I have these dates calculations in a loop and 'curmth' comes from a macro variable which can be any number from 0 to 20 or more. I gave 2 examples with 'curmth' = 0 and 1 only for simplifying and to make it for easy understanding. So, could you please check and provide a dynamic calculation that can take any value for 'curmth' say when it's 3,4,5.,6,7...and so on and provides 'num_mths'. Thanks again!

Comment: How does curmth value affect output? What will be the value of num_mnths if curmth  is 3,4,5 etc

Comment: Yes, the num_mnths value changes for change in 'curmth' value. I've edited my post and added more detailed explanation and examples. Can you please go through it and tweak your code accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Edited the solution.